# Superposition State in Coin Toss

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, superposition

I was reading the following lines from **Quantum Computation and Quantum Information** by **Nielsen and Chuang** on page 278 of chapter 7.

> A coin has two states and makes a good bit but a poor qubit because it cannot remain in a superposition state(of 'heads' and 'tails') for very long

My question is how do I define a general **superposition state** in case of a coin toss?

Comment: $|\text{coin} \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|\text{heads} \rangle + |\text{tails} \rangle\right)$

Comment: but will the probability amplitudes be same all the time?

Comment: Obviously no. As you evolve you act it upon the states by $e^{iHt}$ and since it is a classical object you need to take $\hbar \rightarrow 0$ limit.

Comment: @Jaswin: $\hbar$ is a constant. Nature doesn't care about us changing it. Such a change in theory doesn't lead to a correct physical description of reality, even though older books are (unfortunately) trying to suggest that it's a useful manipulation. What makes the behavior of the coin classical is that it entangles with its environment, which leads to constant weak measurements of its position/attitude, whether we are actively observing it, or not. We simply can't keep it from suffering decoherence.

Comment: @Jaswin Actually I meant to say whether the initial state will be an equal superposition of heads and tails to begin with.

Comment: @SubhadipRoy : Yes you can take them to be an equal superposition.

Comment: @CuriousOne : When i am taking $\hbar \rightarrow 0$, I mean that $|H| >> \hbar $, and the $H$ here involves the entire environment which is generally classical, like the floor, wind, etc. All these things can be neatly approximated as decoherence.

Comment: @Jaswin: I know what it does, it just doesn't do what nature actually does with macroscopic objects. It's a false shortcut that occasionally gives the right results. I am simply not much in favor of those.

Comment: @CuriousOne : Well, it's up to you if you like that approximation or not. Atleast I never came across a counter example where this approximation fails to give the correct result. I didn't get why you say "occasionally gives the right results".

Comment: @Jaswin: Try it on superconductivity, the stability of matter or simple permanent magnetism and tell me how far you get with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the superposition state as $$ \psi = a\uparrow + b\downarrow $$where $a^2 + b^2 = 1 $. But on evolving with a large Hamiltonian, going from one state to another becomes negligible.

Comment: What do you mean by "large Hamiltonian"? and the comment about transitions between states?

Comment: Sorry for being lazy, I meant $|H| >> \hbar $, the magnitude of a classical hamiltonian times t is way bigger than $\hbar$.

Comment: But $H$ and $\hbar$ don't even have the same unit

Comment: Oh that's a typo, OK